# Book recommondation for plotting graphs in LaTeX

Tags: pgfplots

Could anyone suggest a book or website, where I can learn all the features of  mathematical and graph plotting in LaTeX?

Comment: The `pgfplots` manual has a nice set of tutorials. I would start from there: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf.

Comment: Look also at https://pgfplots.net/